# How do I align the parts of a brace diagram?

Tags: align, alignment, cases, braces

I am trying to reproduce the following somewhat complex brace diagram:

[image: Sample brace diagram]

I am having trouble getting the alignment exactly the way I want. Ideally, Category A would be centered in the space delimited by “even longer text” and “short item,” and Category B would be centered over the last column.

For the moment, I have done the alignment of the category titles by eye, and I used the `calc` package to measure the width of the longer texts and force the shorter titles to occupy the same amount of space.

However, this feels like a kludge. Can anyone think of a better way to achieve my goal?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\samesizeas}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][l]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &\samesizeas{$\textsc{longish title}\begin{cases}even longer text\end{cases}$}{}
    \hspace*{-35pt}\text{Category A}
    \samesizeas{short item}{}\hspace*{8pt}\text{Category B} \\[1em]
    &\textsc{longish title}
    \begin{cases}
        \textit{even longer text}
        \begin{cases}
            \textit{short item}
            \begin{cases}
                \textit{item A} \\
                \textit{item B that is longer} \\
                \textit{item C}
            \end{cases} \\
            \textit{item that's a lot longer}
        \end{cases}
    \end{cases} \\
    &\samesizeas{\textsc{longish title}}{\textsc{shorter}}
    \begin{cases}
        \samesizeas{even longer text}{\textit{still short}}
        \begin{cases}
            \samesizeas{\textit{short item}}{\textit{shorter 1}}
            \begin{cases}
                \textit{item A} \\
                \textit{item B} \\
                \textit{item C}
            \end{cases} \\
            \textit{shorter 2}
        \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `cascade` package. It is more simple. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: Unfortunately, `cascade` only allows for lists of two at a time, as far as I can see.

Comment: `schemata` is quite nice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its command `\SubMatrix` to draw the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\itshape
\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}
\RowStyle{\upshape}
  & \Block[c]{}{Category A} && \Block[c]{}{Category B} \\[2mm]
  &&& item A \\
  \Block{2-1}{\textsc{longish title}}&\Block{2-1}{even longer text}& short item & item B that is longer \\
  &&& item C \\
  && \Block[l]{1-2}{item that's a lot longer} \\[2mm]
  \Block{4-1}{\textsc{shorter}}& \Block{4-1}{still short}&& item A \\
  && shorter 1 & item B \\
  &&& item C \\
  && shorter 2 \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\{}{2-2}{5-4}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{2-3}{5-4}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{2-4}{4-4}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{6-2}{9-4}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{6-3}{9-4}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{6-4}{8-4}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Looks fantastic. To make it look exactly as I wanted, I changed `\Block[c]{}{Category A}` to `\Block[c]{1-2}{Category A}`, so that “Category A” straddles the two columns, but otherwise perfect.

Comment: Both answers were good, but I selected this one because it’s perfect as a short and elegant one-off solution.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using `schemata` for this, but I'm not sure it is designed with the features you want in mind. So I decided to try `forest` for the spacing and `calligraphy` for the curly bracket/brace things.

[image: forest + calligraphy for schema]

```
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698199/
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    tier/.option=level,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=child anchor,
    fit=band,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=1{font=\scshape}{font=\itshape},
  },
  where n children=0{no edge}{
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\node (sub-\foresteoption{name}) [fit to=descendants,inner sep=0pt] {};
      \noexpand\draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=10pt},ultra thick] (sub-\foresteoption{name}.south west) -- (sub-\foresteoption{name}.north west); 
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      if level=0{}{%
        tempdima/.max={>O+dO+dw2+d{max y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdimb/.min={>O+dO+dw2+d{min y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdima-/.register=tempdimb,
        tempdima:=2,
        tempdimb+/.register=tempdima,
        y/.register=tempdimb,
      },
    },
  },
  before computing xy={%
    for children={l'=0pt}
  }
  [,coordinate
    [longish title
      [even longer text,name=elt
        [short item,name=si
          [item A]
          [item B that is longer,name=bil]
          [item C]
        ]
        [item that's a lot longer]
      ]
    ]
    [shorter 
      [still short
        [shorter 1
          [item A]
          [item B]
          [item C]
        ]
        [shorter 2]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \node (cat a) [fit=(si) (elt)] {};
  \node (a) [anchor=base,yshift=10pt] at (cat a.center |- current bounding box.north) {Category A};
  \node [anchor=base] at (a.base -| bil.center) {Category B};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

If you need to draw several, this could be turned into a style you could reuse to ensure consistency and avoid repetition. If it is a one-off, that's obviously not relevant. The distance between leaves could also be reduced if the structure looks a bit gappy.

## EDIT

To bring the leaves closer together, we can specify `s sep'=0pt` (for example) in `for tree`.

[image: closing the gap between leaves]

```
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698199/
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    tier/.option=level,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=child anchor,
    fit=band,
    % adjust the minimum distance between 'children' to draw leaves closer together
    s sep'=1pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=1{font=\scshape}{font=\itshape},
  },
  where n children=0{no edge}{
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\node (sub-\foresteoption{name}) [fit to=descendants,inner sep=0pt] {};
      \noexpand\draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=10pt},ultra thick] (sub-\foresteoption{name}.south west) -- (sub-\foresteoption{name}.north west); 
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      if level=0{}{%
        tempdima/.max={>O+dO+dw2+d{max y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdimb/.min={>O+dO+dw2+d{min y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdima-/.register=tempdimb,
        tempdima:=2,
        tempdimb+/.register=tempdima,
        y/.register=tempdimb,
      },
    },
  },
  before computing xy={%
    for children={l'=0pt}
  }
  [,coordinate
    [longish title
      [even longer text,name=elt
        [short item,name=si
          [item A]
          [item B that is longer,name=bil]
          [item C]
        ]
        [item that's a lot longer]
      ]
    ]
    [shorter 
      [still short
        [shorter 1
          [item A]
          [item B]
          [item C]
        ]
        [shorter 2]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \node (cat a) [fit=(si) (elt)] {};
  \node (a) [anchor=base,yshift=10pt] at (cat a.center |- current bounding box.north) {Category A};
  \node [anchor=base] at (a.base -| bil.center) {Category B};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

This probably isn't ideal. Adjusting the separation of just the leaves and reducing the padding inside them using Ti*k*Z's `inner sep` may be better.

[image: adjusted separation of leaves and leaf nodes]

```
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698199/
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    tier/.option=level,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=child anchor,
    fit=band,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level=1{font=\scshape}{font=\itshape},
  },
  where n children=0{no edge,s sep'=0pt,inner ysep=0pt}{
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\node (sub-\foresteoption{name}) [fit to=descendants,inner sep=0pt] {};
      \noexpand\draw [decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=10pt},ultra thick] (sub-\foresteoption{name}.south west) -- (sub-\foresteoption{name}.north west); 
    },
    before drawing tree={%
      if level=0{}{%
        tempdima/.max={>O+dO+dw2+d{max y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdimb/.min={>O+dO+dw2+d{min y}{y}{#1+#2}}{descendants},
        tempdima-/.register=tempdimb,
        tempdima:=2,
        tempdimb+/.register=tempdima,
        y/.register=tempdimb,
      },
    },
  },
  before computing xy={%
    for children={l'=0pt}
  }
  [,coordinate
    [longish title
      [even longer text,name=elt
        [short item,name=si
          [item A]
          [item B that is longer,name=bil]
          [item C]
        ]
        [item that's a lot longer]
      ]
    ]
    [shorter 
      [still short
        [shorter 1
          [item A]
          [item B]
          [item C]
        ]
        [shorter 2]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \node (cat a) [fit=(si) (elt)] {};
  \node (a) [anchor=base,yshift=10pt] at (cat a.center |- current bounding box.north) {Category A};
  \node [anchor=base] at (a.base -| bil.center) {Category B};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I’m new to `forest`, so I’m still wrapping my head around the code. Could you point me in the direction of how to make the leaves closer together?

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex See edit above. I'd change `s sep`, basically, which is the separation of children. Above, I've done this for the whole tree and also for only the leaves, with an adjustment to `inner sep`.